# App Engine GQL Query - Sorting

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gql

Having some issues with merging two GQLQueries in GAE (python).

```
  fp_events = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE firstPlayer=:1", alias).fetch(mylimit)
  sp_events = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE secondPlayer=:1", alias).fetch(mylimit)
  events = fp_events.append(sp_events)
```

However, when I try to iterate through these events using the for loop `for event in events:`, I get a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable` error at that line.  I suspect that this has something to do with the append I attempt to do, though I'm not entirely sure.

These events also have a datetime property... how could I sort the resulting events list by time, descending?  While I could use `ORDER BY time DESC` in the two queries above, their merger isn't necessarily guaranteed to be sorted.

I should also mention that the firstPlayer and secondPlayer properties for the Event table are mutually exclusive (no event has both firstPlayer and secondPlayer set to the same player).

Thank-you!

Comment: Do you always want the entire result set of these queries, or might you only want the first n results from the combination of them? If the latter, there are more efficient ways to do this with a merge operation than fetching all the results and sorting them.

Comment: FYI: The result of calling `append` is `None`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list` to convert the iterable objects into Python lists:

```
fp_events = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE firstPlayer = :1", alias).fetch(mylimit)
sp_events = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Event WHERE secondPlayer = :1", alias).fetch(mylimit)
```

To combine the two lists, try this:

```
fp_events_list = list(fp_events)
sp_events_list = list(sp_events)
events = fp_events_list + sp_events_list
```

I just tried that out in the remote shell against one of my own AppEngine datastores, and it definitely works.

I'm afraid that in order to get the sorting that you want, you'll have to use sort them with [the sorted builtin](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/):

```
sorted_events = sorted(events, key=lambda event: event.time)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the OR clause is currently unsupported by GQL.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still isn't working for me:/  The fact that OR is unsupported certainly makes this sort of thing a headache.

Comment: Are you still getting the same error that's in your question? Can you add some logging to confirm that fp_events and sp_events are both `not None`?

Comment: Yeah... I actually don't think a.append(b) or a.extend(b) is valid syntax for queries like this, but I'm not sure what to use instead to combine the two.

Comment: Awesome, that works perfectly, thank-you!  I just need `sorted_events` in reverse order, but that should be easy to do.  Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, just had to toss in a 'reverse=True' into the arguments list

Comment: Right you are, Guido. Edited my answer to reflect the actual cause. I was conflating the requirement that when you use the `.filter()` method, there has to be a space between the name of the property and filtering operator (e.g. `.filter('firstPlayer =')`) with GQL syntax.

Comment: There's no need to call `list` - because `.fetch` was called on the query, `fp_events` and `sp_events` are already lists. Calling `.fetch` is also much more efficient than calling `list` on a query.