# Google App Engine Datastore 200 index limit (index.yaml)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, indexing, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Using: Google App Engine, Python 2.7, Google NDB Datastore, GQL.

I writing a business application that has many NDB kind(ndb.Model) 
ex: Customers,Vendors,Suppliers,Manufacture,Orders etc..

I like to present the user with information sorted by various Entity/fields:

Examples of: index.yaml - Customer class will have maybe 12-15 index file entries.

```
- kind: Customers
  - properties:
  - name: Name
  - name: NewDate
  - direction: desc
- kind: Customers
  - properties:
  - name: State
  - name: Name
- kind: Customers
  - properties:
  - name: Country
  - name: Name
- kind: Customer
  - properties:
  - name: Code
  - name: Name
  - name: Class
  - name: LastOrderDate
  - direction: desc
```

Just an example but I like to have about 20-30 NDB kind(ndb.Model)s with about 15 composite indexes each. I like to make sure I have a workaround if I run into the 200 limit.

Not sure why Google would limit this at 200, I think the limit should be per each NDB kind(ndb.Model) maybe 20 per?

Thank you for any suggestion

Comment: The new App Engine SDK - Release Notes Version 1.9.0 - February 26, 2014 talks about: "There is no fixed limit on the number of indexes" is this only for Search API or for all custom index for application???

Comment: Issue 8305: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=8305   is addressing this, as I stated I think the limit should be per each NDB kind

Answer (score 3):

You need to think again about your data model. Your main problem is not a limit of 200 indexes. If you implement the model that you are contemplating, your indexes will take many times more storage space than your data, and your write costs will be astronomical.

Every time you save a data object, you will incur writing costs per entity plus per each indexed property plus per each custom index. With your data model you will end up paying 15-20 times more per each update of every entity than is necessary.

You probably have experience with SQL databases, but the datastore is very different. You have to model your data differently.

I built a very complex app with dozens of different entities with very complex relationships between them. I have 5 custom indexes in this app.

EDIT:

There are many approaches to data modeling in non-relational databases. Let's take, for example, your example of "name AND state" index. How many customers are going to have the same name, but in different states? It's much cheaper to retrieve all customers with a given name, and then choose the ones that belong to the required state, rather than create a custom index just for this combination of properties. Remember that reads are much cheaper than writes, plus you have a smaller data size.

The same applies to all of your examples. Instead of "code AND name AND class AND LastOrderDate" you can select all customers by name and order date, and in a very rare case when two customers have the same name, just drop the one with the wrong code/class.

Comment: Andrei, thank for the reply. I have (indexed=False) on most of the fields but because of the Multi-corp, Multi-user, security, access to customer information it gets complicated and custom index get created.

Comment: Additionally users have an export feature that allows them to select from drop down field values in 1 - 3 fields that exports information based on selections.

Comment: Between the lines the last comment reveals a "porting an existing relational data model to Datastore" scenario.  I upvote Andrei because the design should embrace cloud and let go of third normal form.  If that causes feature pain, reduce user expectations in the cloud version of the app.  It's not worth pushing the platform hard on things it does inefficiently.  On the other hand storage and reading are cheap so you may be able to keep a lot of functionality by over-reading and discarding lots of records as Andrei suggested.

Comment: You can add a sort order on any indexed property. Just remember that if you use an inequality filter, it should be sorted first.

Comment: Andrei/Martin thanks again for the help. if I do this: ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE State = :1 ORDER BY DateRecordCreated DESC" , State ) an Index.yaml record gets created, what would be you recommendation on doing this without custom index. I have many that work with DateCreated DESC order

Comment: If you try to retrieve all records, you don't have to sort them in your query - you can retrieve them and sort them yourself. In fact, you may not even need to sort them at all, but simply filter by a criteria (like, after a certain date), which is extremely fast.

Comment: The new App Engine SDK - Release Notes Version 1.9.0 - February 26, 2014 talks about: "There is no fixed limit on the number of indexes" is this only for Search API or for all custom index for application?

Comment: Good answer for sort after GQL result: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11637677/app-engine-gql-query-sorting

Comment: I guess the recommendation is to "over-read" from the datastore then "sort" and/or "discard" unneeded records